# 404 error in HttpPost Ajax call ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am trying to post a file in an Ajax request. It is working in Localhost but not after publish on server, it is always returning 404.

I don't know if it is a route problem.

I appreciate if someone can give me some idea.

My code is here:

View:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="files"
             name="files" multiple />
<input type="button"
             id="upload"
             value="Upload Selected Files" />
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadFilesAjax()
    {
        long size = 0;
        var files = Request.Form.Files;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue
                                            .Parse(file.ContentDisposition)
                                            .FileName
                                            .Trim('"');
            filename = hostingEnv.WebRootPath + $@"\{filename}";
            size += file.Length;
            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filename))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fs);
                fs.Flush();
            }
        }
        string message = $"{files.Count} file(s) / {size} bytes uploaded successfully!";

        return Json(message);

    }
```

Javascript:

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    j(document).ready(function () {
        j("#upload").click(function (evt) {
            var fileUpload = $("#files").get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;
            var data = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length ; i++) {
                data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Exemplos/UploadFilesAjax",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                success: function (message) {
                    alert(message);
                },
                error: function (e) {

                    alert("There was error uploading files!");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Check the network calls in devtools and see the url is correct (Using the Url.Action helper method to generate the correct url is a good start , than hard coding the url). Also do not post images, post the code with proper formatting.

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of images. What is the broken URL on the server? It's safer to write the url into the form action (with a Razor helper) and read it into your script instead of writing out a relative path -- which can break when you move the code into a different environment. `var url = $("#myform").attr("action")`.

Comment: Guys, I posted the code.

Comment: Is the 404 url "correct"? Is your application installed and listening on that route?

Comment: If you remove the internals for `UploadFilesAjax` and simply return a success response, do you still get an error?

Comment: What is the domain you have posted the code? Either it contains any subpath like "example.com/sub/ "? You can try by adding full URL in ajax call.

Answer (score 5):

As I have noticed in you POST method there is no route opened to the URL you defined. Please add route to the HttpPost attribute. It would looks like below,

```
[HttpPost("/Exemplos/UploadFilesAjax")]
public IActionResult UploadFilesAjax()
{
    long size = 0;
    var files = Request.Form.Files;
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue
                                        .Parse(file.ContentDisposition)
                                        .FileName
                                        .Trim('"');
        filename = hostingEnv.WebRootPath + $@"\{filename}";
        size += file.Length;
        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filename))
        {
            file.CopyTo(fs);
            fs.Flush();
        }
    }
    string message = $"{files.Count} file(s) / {size} bytes uploaded successfully!";

    return Json(message);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem by adding `Route` attribute on `controller` class like this:

```
[Route("/AreaName/[controller]/[action]")] // <-- this line
[ApiController]
public class GlobalController : ControllerBase
{
 ...
}
```

NOTE: if you haven't `area` remove `AreaName` part from rout path.